# How to determine RGB values from cluster center using K-means?

Tags: matlab, image-processing, k-means, image-segmentation

I am using K-means to segmented colour in image and right now I want to get RGB values from each colour that already been cluster. And one more thing, Can anyone explain to me why cluster center have two values(*6 x 2 double*)? Is it this is the range of cluster center?something?

```
cform = makecform('srgb2lab');
lab = applycform(a,cform);

ab = double(lab(:,:,2:3));
nrows = size(ab,1);
ncols = size(ab,2);
ab = reshape(ab,nrows*ncols,2);

nColors = 6;
[cluster_idx, cluster_center] = kmeans(ab, nColors,   
                                       'distance','sqEuclidean', 'Replicates', 3);
pixel_labels = reshape(cluster_idx, nrows, ncols);
segmented_images = cell(1,3);
rgb_label = repmat(pixel_labels,[1 1 3]);
```

Comment: ofc cluster center have 2 values, if it was only 1 value - say 16, how would you interpret that? the 16th pixel? the 16th row? to read the RGB value, apply your cluster to the original image (before the LAB step) and read the RGB values

Comment: I assume that your image is 2D (excluding the colour dimension)? in which  case the centres need two values, a row and a column coordinate.

Comment: Does is it mean that cluster center is a coordinate which represent RGB value?

Comment: @GameOfThrows Thank you for your comment. May I know how to apply my cluster to original image?Actually, i am not very clear what is cluster center stand for? Is it represent X and Y coordinate pixel of original image? or represent LAB values?  I already apply cluster center( as coordinate x and y) to original image but i got different result.

Answer (score 0):

Your `cluster_center` is 6-by-2 since you asked `kmeans` to compute `nColors=6` (i.e., `k=6`) centers in a color space of only `a` and `b` components of the `Lab` color space.

In order to get RGB values from these 6 centers you can

1. Fix some default  value, `L'` for the `L` component, and convert back the L'ab centers into RGB values.
2. Use the `cluster_idx` masks to compute the average color of each segment in the original RGB image.